# How to disable pod editing in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a cluster on Azure composed by some pods installed by helmfile and managed by kubernetes. Now all users can execute kubectl edit on the pods and can change docker image version and environment variables. How can I disable this operation? I wish all changes were made by helmfile.

I read about RBAC policy but they don't allow to create rules for deny.

Comment: Deny rules are indeed not part of RBAC (and probably they will never be). So the only way to go at this is ensuring someone has the permissions that they should have.  See this post on github why they decided this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/85963#issuecomment-708403412